# soapUi I get No signature of method error in Groovy script

Tags: soapui

When using this code in soapUI:

```
import com.eviware.soapui.model.mock.MockRequest;

MockRequest.getHttpResponse();
```

I get this error:

```
java.lang.Exception: No signature of method: static     com.eviware.soapui.model.mock.MockRequest.getHttpResponse() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
```

Please can you help?

Comment: Is there an actual mock step?

Comment: or try mockRequest.getHttpResponse(); this is with a smallcase m for mockRequest